# div align creating new line

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am using below code

```
​<div align="left">
Line 1
</div>
<div align="right">
Line 2
</div>
```

I was expecting output as `Line 1` at left side and `Line2` at right side on same line, however I get output in two line. How can I get this in one line?

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zqJY/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="float: left">Line 1</div>
<div style="text-align: right">Line 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're new to HTML/CSS, so I'd suggest that you read some beginner tutorials on how styling works.

A div element is set to "display: block" by default, so what you are seeing is the intended behavior. The width of the first div is taking up the entire width of the parent element, so when the second div is rendered it drops to the line below (as it can no longer fit "next to" the first div.

As other answers have noted, you want to set the style to float left or right (the width of the element will change accordingly).

Here's the new fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/7zqJY/3/**  ​

Comment: and I think you are new to jsfiddle... You didn't hit **Update** button to save the changes that you made :D :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width:100px;">
  Line 1
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:100px;">
  Line 2
</div>
​
```